# Insert only paid account numbers into a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to VBA. I need to copy all paid account numbers into Column A of the current sheet. The Accounts sheet has the account numbers in column A and in column B either "Paid" or "Unpaid". I just keep getting error after error and I'm not sure if I'm fixing it or making it worse, but the last error I couldn't get past was for the line `Cells(t,1).Value =i`: "Application Defined or Object Defined Error."

```
Sub Button1_Click()

  Dim t As Integer
  Dim i As Range

  Dim sheet As Worksheet
  Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts")

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Worksheets("accounts").Range("A:A")

  'starting with cell A2
  target = 2
  'For each account number in Accounts
  For Each i In rng
  'find if it's paid or not
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, sheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False) = "PAID" Then
      'if so, put it in the target cell
      Cells(t, 1).Value = i
      t = t + 1
    End If
  Cells(t, 1).Value = i
  t = t + 1
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: sheet name `accounts` and `Accounts`, will they be treated same? Please look into it.

Comment: I have submitted 3 program versions. Even if we consider `VLOOKUP` , it is normally for a single look-up value in the left  most column. Workaround may be possible for multiple criteria which imho may require a concatenated key, hence requiring extra effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Auto filter.
Samples of sheets are appended below.

[image: Accounts Sheet]
[image: current for paid accounts]

Try this :

```
 Sub Test2()
     Dim LastRow As Long
    Sheets("current").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
       With Worksheets("Accounts")
         .Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Paid"
         LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         .Range("B1:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("current").Range("A1")
      End With
End Sub
```

******Another Program version ******************

This updates the accounts for "Paid Status" . Requires Account IDs to be present in the current sheet and criteria to be mentioned in Accounts Sheets `E1 Cell`

[image: accounts version 2][image: current version 2]

Code snippet is appended below:

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, colStatus As Long, lastrowplus As Long, lastrowminus As Long

    colStatus = 2 'your status column number
    lastrowplus = Sheets("Accounts").Cells(Sheets("Accounts").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowminus = Sheets("current").Cells(Sheets("current").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastrowplus
        For j = 1 To lastrowminus
            If Sheets("Accounts").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("current").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            If Sheets("current").Cells(j, colStatus).Value = Sheets("current").Cells(1, 4).Value Then
                Sheets("current").Cells(j, colStatus).Value = Sheets("Accounts").Cells(i, colStatus).Value
            End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

******Third Program Alternative********

This approach is based upon creating object `Scripting.Dictionary`.
For relatively simple needs, such as identifying only the distinct items in a list, there is no advantage to using a Dictionary from a feature functionality perspective.  However, if you must:

-Retrieve keys as well as the items associated with those keys;
-Handle case-sensitive keys; and/or
-Be able to accommodate changes in items and/or keys

then using a Dictionary object offers a compelling alternative to a Collection.
 However, even for relatively simple needs, a Dictionary may offer a significant performance advantage. May like to refer the following link.

[VBA for smarties: Dictionaries](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

We will have to create additional column in current sheet which should be filled with string "Paid" as additional criteria for matching is required. It can be made a hidden column in the sheet. Please also set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library. Data is populated in the arrays. and program run matches `AccountsID+Prog_status` on current sheet to `AccountID+Status` fields for a match. Matching keys are updated in current sheet in the Status field.
Sample images of current and Accounts Sheet are appended below.

[image: Dictionary approach account Sheet]
[image: dictionary approach current sheet]

Code snippet as follows:

```
  Sub test2()
    Dim a, i As Long, txt As String, result
    a = Sheets("Accounts").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
            txt = Join(Array(a(i, 1), a(i, 2)), Chr(2))
            .Item(txt) = a(i, 2)
        Next
        a = Sheets("current").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
        ReDim result(1 To UBound(a, 1) - 1, 1 To 1)
        For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
            txt = Join(Array(a(i, 1), a(i, 3)), Chr(2))
            result(i - 1, 1) = .Item(txt)
        Next
    End With
    Sheets("current").Range("B2").Resize(UBound(result, 1)).Value = result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that I just created:

```
Sub GetPaid()

    Dim cells As Range
    Set cells = Range("A1:B10")

    Dim name As String
    Dim paid As String
    Dim insertAt As Integer
    insertAt = 1

    For Each r In cells.Rows

        name = r.cells(1, 1).Value
        paid = r.cells(1, 2).Value

        If paid = "PAID" Then
            MsgBox name & " has paid!"
            CopyToSheet "Sheet1", insertAt, name

            insertAt = insertAt + 1
        End If

    Next r

End Sub

Sub CopyToSheet(SheetName As String, InsertAtRow As Integer, Value As String)
    Sheets(SheetName).cells(InsertAtRow, 1).Value = Value
End Sub
```

Apologies for my great variable names! I hope this helps you out. :)

Comment: I know you commented about it, but I'm just noting that I would shy away from using `cells` as a variable name. Notice how you use `cells` to be a range, but also you use the VB `Cells()` to set variables...this could cause confusion.  I tend to use `cel` or `rng`, or perhaps `xCells`.  Just a note anyway.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, I totally agree with that!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't u use this.

```
 Sub Button1_Click()

        Sheets("Accounts").activate ' your first sheet
        Range("A1").select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select ' select the first value to the last
        for each MyCell in Selection
            i = i + 1
            if MyCell.value = "PAID" then ' if the active cell has my value then
                sheets("SecondSheets").Cells(i,1).value = MyCell.Value ' throw this value to the next sheet
            end if 
        next MyCell

    end sub
```

Hope it Help.